# How to Load Video Thumbnail From Video Url in ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-videoview, listview-adapter

I have a `ListView` and I want to populate it with video form a URL. I can show Pictures in ListView adapter easily from URL, but how to load a video thumbnail?

Comment: Can you share your JSON response or API which you called.!

Comment: yes I am getting all the exact path of video and images but the images how and video thumnail does not shows

Comment: Many image-loading libraries, like Picasso, can obtain the thumbnail for you, when you provide the `Uri` to the video.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to get your video thumbnail.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String videoPath = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        try {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                // no headers included
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
            else
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) 
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null)
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_id)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Can I use this inside listview adapter for more thumnails to load?

Comment: @ It can load one video thumnails in listviewadapter, but can not load more thumnails for other videos in the same listviewadapter

Comment: You have to implement a callback after receiving a bitmap and update your adapter's imageview.

Comment: how cabn  i do that please can you can tell me, I am really stuck in this listviewadapter