# Is there any way to create thumbnail from video URL?

Tags: android, video, video-thumbnails

Want to create `tumbnails` from url from any sites.
I am using following code

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail;
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoLink, 
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

But its not working,please suggest any other ways if present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Generate a thumbnail from a video url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android)

Comment: Possible Duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522124/android-display-a-video-thumbnail-from-a-url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android
Refer Also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956167/how-to-load-video-thumbnail-from-video-url-in-listview-adapter
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943830/5018132

Answer (score 10):

Use Glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Shortest Method To get Video `thumbnails`

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.isMemoryCacheable();
Glide.with(context).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load("Url").into(image);
```

Comment: Above works but take too much time video

Answer (score 1):

If there is youtube url, then we have to make static url to make it thumbnail. `https://img.youtube.com/vi/nE4PBsClUrY/0.jpg`

`nE4PBsClUrY` - this is id of video

Using that we can make a thumbnail.